# How to create identity column with another column?

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have a table contains three columns (ID, Shop & User).

ID & Shop are composite primary keys

I want to generate identity number according to the shop.

For example,
No. 1 user for shop A
No. 2 user for shop A
No. 1 user for shop B

How do I generate this identity number according to the shop.

**NumberID**
ID int identity,
Shop varchar(100),
user varchar(100)

Comment: T-SQL is specific for Sybase/MsSQL. I see that you tagged your question as MySQL. Which database are you using?

Comment: Sorry I wanna try with both MSSQL & MYSQL

Comment: Do you want "one solution" to work on both types of databases? The syntax of MsSQL may be different than that of MySQL.

Comment: I am looking for a DB specific type that could do this. Moreover, If there is DB Specific type in either on of those, I want to know a solution and it does not have to be a common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in the "create statement/s" of the table itself is database-type specific. It also demands for specific DB expertise (to handle tricky things like startup counter, auto increment value, jumps in value during parallel transactions for efficiency, taking care of counter during backup/restore, complexity of doing for part of primary key). May be some database experts will answer it in a bullet-proof way.

In the meantime, here is how you could do it in MySQL within the "insert statement" itself (by running it atomically). This could also work in a trigger/procedure (based on your circumstances on how much you want to protect developers from accidentally inserting duplicates). If you do it in a procedure, you could give the procedure as your main interface to the developers (and take out access for them from inserting directly into table).

**MySQL 5.6 Schema/Inserts**:

```
create table tt
(
   id int, shop varchar(100), user varchar(100)
 );


insert into tt values (
  ifnull((select max(id) from tt a where a.shop='shop1'),0)+1,
  'shop1',
  'user1'
);

insert into tt values (
  ifnull((select max(id) from tt a where a.shop='shop1'),0)+1,
  'shop1',
  'user1'
);
```

**Query**:

```
select * from tt
```

**[Results]**:

```
| id |  shop |  user |
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 | shop1 | user1 |
|  2 | shop1 | user1 |
```